# iOS 13 Presenting Modal half screen for iOS, popover for iPadOS

Tags: popover, uipopovercontroller, ios13, presentmodalviewcontroller

[image]

What I'm looking to achieve is the exact same behavior as share view of iOS 13. I want to present my custom picker view as popover on iPad, and as semi modal on iPhone. I'm currently using "present as popover" on storyboard, which I get the default behavior that auto switches between popover and modal for free. I guess I need to switch to custom controller, but I'm lost on how to achieve this.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?

Comment: Unfortunately nope, but I'll post my solution here once I found one. I plan to implement a custom segue controller. If I recall correctly, Apple mentioned this topic in 18 or 19 WWDC, in the talk about new behavior changes for modal presentation. They also mentioned a new custom method.

Comment: After some research I believe it may the ios 13 new share sheet.